# How to make some piece of text inside a input field non editable?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a requirement that I have a input field of maxLength 4.among these 4 characters first 2 characters will be "FR".Remaining 2 character will be inserted by user.So,during the page loading time I have called a Jquery Function and set the value "FR" like this

```
  $('.testData').val("FR");
```

****Now,When user will edit the remaining two character's he will not be allowed to edit the piece of text "FR"**.**neither he is allowed to delete this text "FR"**

**by setting**

```
<input type="text" readonly>
```

**it will make the entire input field non editable,I donot want that,I only want to put restriction on editing on first 2 characters.**

can anyone give any solution to this???

Comment: This seems like it could cause a usability issue... Can you use two separate textboxes for this purpose? Otherwise the user will have no idea what is editable and what isn't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no substantial attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: why not just have FR as a label, and not even inside the input field?

Comment: You could attach an `onkeyup` event to the field and check the value of the field in that event. If the first two characters of the string are not 'FR', either prepend the current string with 'FR', or replace the first two characters of the current string with 'FR' (your choice on what logic to implement).

Comment: no I cannot use FR as label its requiement of my project.actually the input field represents IBAN number of a country.@Brian

Answer (score 3):

A hacky solution, but kinda does the trick using JS.

```
<input id="myId" type="text" value="AZ"></input>

$("#myId").keydown(function(event){
    console.log(this.selectionStart);
    console.log(event);
    if(event.keyCode == 8){
        this.selectionStart--;
    }
    if(this.selectionStart < 2){
        this.selectionStart = 2;
        console.log(this.selectionStart);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$("#myId").keyup(function(event){
    console.log(this.selectionStart);
    if(this.selectionStart < 2){
        this.selectionStart = 2;
        console.log(this.selectionStart);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JZzFV/1/)!

Comment: do I need to add any jquery library in my project for your above mention code???bcz its not working in my project.@Izaaz Yunus

Comment: Yes you need to add the jquery library. You can use the one found [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js)