# How to make some piece of text inside a input field non editable? - Extended

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks Izaaz Yunus for the answer at [How to make some piece of text inside a input field non editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157115/how-to-make-some-piece-of-text-inside-a-input-field-non-editable)

The two characters working for me.But the requirement is slight different for me.

I am getting the some part of, non editable characters of text filed form ajax/dynamically call, AND the length is not fixed.

It can be 1 or 2 or 3.It is the phone code of countries.so it can be "1", "91", "255"(min length 1 and max 3)

Please help me on your own answer.

Manu

Comment: Provide the sample code you have developed so far

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve.
create a global variable

```
<script>
    var countryCodeLength = 0;
```

set this variable on ajax call.

```
success : function(response) {
                $('#contactNo').val(response);
                countryCodeLength = $('#contactNo').val().length;
```

and use this on prevent.

```
$("#contactNo").keydown(function(event){
            console.log(this.selectionStart);
            console.log(event);
            if(event.keyCode == 8){
                this.selectionStart--;
            }
            if(this.selectionStart < countryCodeLength){
                this.selectionStart = countryCodeLength;
                console.log(this.selectionStart);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```